# Javascript slider loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, slider

I have been trying to create an image slider for html by changing the value of the image element, using a loop to go through each image and then returning to the original image.

However once it reaches the end of the loop it doesn't continue.

Here is my Js code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = 0
  while(x<1000){
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('carousel').src='img/header2.jpg';
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('carousel').src='img/header3.jpg';
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('carousel').src='img/header.jpg';
          }, 5000);
        }, 5000);
      }, 5000);
    x = x+1
  }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon on your x increment line.

Comment: That's not needed.

Comment: I did something similar a while back. Maybe my fiddle will give you some guidance: https://jsfiddle.net/Currell/wb0o99cq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to not do `while` loop in this case. Just recall `setTimeout` when executed.

```
window.onload = function() {
     /* Element */
    var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
     /* Carousel current image */
    cimage = 2,
     /* Carousel source images */
    csources = [
        'img/header2.jpg',
        'img/header3.jpg',
        'img/header.jpg'
    ];

    function changeCarouselImage() {
        // Reset the current image if it's ultrapassing the length - 1
        if(cimage >= 3) cimage = 0;
        // Change the source image
        carousel.src = csources[cimage ++];
        // Re-call the function after 5s
        setTimeout(changeCarouselImage, 5000);
    }

    setTimeout(changeCarouselImage, 5000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The final function does not set another timeout, and thus the animation does not continue. Seperating into individual functions should help:

```
var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');

function ani1() {
    carousel.src = 'img/header.jpg';
    window.setTimeout(ani2, 500);
}

function ani2() {
    carousel.src = 'img/header2.jpg';
    window.setTimeout(ani3, 500);
}

function ani3() {
    carousel.src = 'img/header3.jpg';
    window.setTimeout(ani1, 500);
}

window.onload = ani1;
```

Comment: thanks this works, however doesn't repeat through the images again? Sorry i'm new to javascript.